# C - remove() - Error 2 (File does not exist), but file exists

Tags: c, input, delete-file

In C, I want to delete a file by 1) accepting the file name as input then 2) removing the file.

However, when I supply the name of a file that exists, I get error code 2 from the remove() function ('file does not exist').

I have tried using 1) just the name of the file and 2) the full path of the file. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<dirent.h>

    int main()
    {
        // sanity check; print names of all files in current dir
        DIR *d;
        struct dirent *dir;
        d = opendir(".");

        if (d)
        {
            while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
            {
                printf("%s\n", dir->d_name); // prints 'testfile.txt' (and others)
            }

            closedir(d);
        }

        char buffer[101];

        printf("Name of file to delete: ");
        char *result = fgets(buffer, 101, stdin); 
        /*
        input tried: 'testfile.txt', 'full/path to/testfile.txt',
                     'full/path\ to/testfile.txt'
        (all less than 101 chars)
        */

        if (remove(result) == 0)
            printf("File %s deleted.\n", result);
        else
            printf("%d\n", errno); // always prints 2 ('file does not exist' error)
            fprintf(stderr, "Error deleting the file %s\n", result); // as given in input

        return 0;
    }
```

Why is remove() failing with error code 2? How can I fix it?

Comment: The buffer you capture probably contains a '\n' character.  You have to remove it.

Comment: Tried `perror()` ?

Comment: @ryyker that was it. i didn't realize there might be a '\n' char at the end of input. thank you.